# Переполнение словаря в python и его последствия

Tags: python, python-3.x

Один ключ словаря принимает следующее значение(скорее на столько же больше)

```
{177632508: [
    [],
    [],
    [],
    ['Технология', 'История', 'История', 'Литература', 'ЭК Общ', 'Физкультура', 'Английский язык'],
    ['Биология', 'ЭК Психология', 'Физкультура', 'Русский язык', 'Химия', 'Английский язык'],
    ['Искусство (МХК)', 'ЭК Рус. язык', 'Информатика и ИКТ', 'Биология', 'Английский язык', 'ЭК ОБЖ']
]
}
```

Если подобных ключей в словаре будет 100-1000 или даже больше, то грозит ли это какими-либо последствиями? Если да, то как периодически очищать его, не отключая саму программу?

Comment: Вроде ничем не должно грозить, кроме очевидно повышенного потребления оперативы

Comment: @andreymal Если сама программа будет запущена на сервере, то никак не отразится, верно?

Comment: @r4d1f что вы понимаете под "никак не отразится"? Где будет запущена, там и потратит оперативку.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вопрос не до конца понятен. Стандартно хеш (словарь) устроен как массив слотов, каждый из которых содержит массив или список элементов. В какой слот попадет заданный ключ, определяется остатком от деления значения хеш-функции на длину массива слотов. При добавлении/удалении элементов подсчитывается среднее количество элементов на слот. Если оно превосходит некоторое число, хеш перестраивается примерно следующим образом:

1. Массив слотов перерезервируется с большей длиной.
2. Все элементы хеша перераспределяются по новому массиву, поскольку остатки от деления на новую длину меняются.

Понятно, что это довольно "тяжелая" операция. Чем еще грозит, не могу себе представить. Как можно обойти: резервировать хеш сразу с заданным количеством слотов, примерно соответствующим задаче. Из скрипта так делать нельзя, но возможно, поможет C API или даже допрограммирование исходников интерпретатора. Если это важно, то можно и на такое пойти.

*Нашел у себя скрипт, иллюстрирующий явление, потому дополняю ответ.*

Давайте попробуем добавить в словарь последовательно 10 миллионов элементов с ключами от "key 1" до "key 10000000", при этом отдельно выделим элементы, время добавления которых более чем в тысячу раз превосходит среднее на данный момент:

```
from time import time
from pprint import pprint

table = {}
info = []
midtime = 0.

for i in range(1, 10000000):
    t = time()
    table['key %d' % i] = ''
    t = time() - t
    if t > midtime*1000: info.append((i, t))
    midtime += (t - midtime) / i;

pprint(info)
print("midtime = ", midtime)
```

И результат на моей машине:

```
[(1, 3.814697265625e-06),
 (10924, 0.0007479190826416016),
 (21846, 0.0018160343170166016),
 (43692, 0.00409388542175293),
 (87382, 0.00872659683227539),
 (174764, 0.017720699310302734),
 (349526, 0.035208940505981445),
 (699052, 0.07481122016906738),
 (1398102, 0.15592074394226074),
 (2796204, 0.3201014995574951),
 (5592406, 0.6474840641021729)]
midtime =  9.339096049571132e-07
```

Видно, что время вставки элемента с ключем "key 5592406" более чем в полмиллиона раз превосходит среднее время вставки, и само по себе больше, чем полсекунды. Это связанно именно с перестройкой большого словаря.